# Two different syntax structure for Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, autohotkey

I'm using using **[AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/)** to drive **[SeleniumBasic v2.0.9.0](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0)**

I'm new to Selenium and have been looking at a lot of different pages discussing how to get/set elements on a webpage.  I've noticed there seems to be (at least )two different types of format for syntax.
Here are two examples:

```
 1. driver.findElementByID("search_form_input_homepage").SendKeys("hello")
 2. driver.findElement(By.id("search_form_input_homepage")).SendKeys("hello")
```

In my case the first one works but the second throws an error saying `No such interface supported`. I'm just curious of the origin of the second structure.  Is it from Selenium 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

1. `driver.findElementByID("search_form_input_homepage").SendKeys("hello")` : Is in use through the VBA module maintained by @FlorentB.
2. `driver.findElement(By.id("search_form_input_homepage")).SendKeys("hello")` : Is in use through the Java bindings of Selenium.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Awesome!   Thank you!

Comment: Done!  Thank you again!   I'd searched around a lot but hadn't seen anybody explain the difference (and didn't notice the pattern)

Comment: My pleasure :) Keep a watch on SeleniumBasic v2.0.9.0 in github. @FlorentB. mentioned in a thread to release a new version soon. Thanks